# Incorrect syntax near '?' while executing the query

Tags: node.js, connection-pooling

I am using Node js with mssql. And got error Incorrect syntax near '?'

```
 let pool  = await sql.connect(dbObject.config);
let result1 = await pool.request().query(`insert into saleDiscount (name, percentage, IsActive) values (?,?,?)`,[name,percentage, checkboxBinary]);
console.log(result1);
sql.close();
```

Comment: What is it? Your tags says `mysql` your question is talking about `mssql`?

Comment: Are you sure that the MSSQL driver works with `?` placeholders? [The documentation](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#queries) suggests otherwise.

Comment: I don't know i am trying this first time.

Comment: Well, how about trying it with the help of the docs. And using the syntax from the docs You probably worked with a mysql driver before, where the above is the correct way to execute parameterized queries . With mssql it's a bit different ...